# SQL Incorrect SUMS from multiple JOINS

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to sum multiple tables using Joins and Sums in MySQL and not having much success.

**My Tables (Unnecessary Columns Removed)**

**Students**

```
idStudent   studentname   studentyear
1           foobar        11
2           barfoo        11
3           thing         8
```

**Athletics_Results**

```
idResult   idStudent   points
1          1           14
2          1           11
3          3           7
4          2           9
```

**Team_Results**

```
idTeamResults   year   points
1               11     9
2               8      8
3               7      14
```

So let me explain about the tables, because I admit they're poorly named and designed.

Students holds the basic info about each student, including their year and name. Each student has a unique ID.

Athletics_Results stores the results from athletics events. The idStudent column is a foreign key and relates to idStudent in the student column. So student foobar (idStudent 1) has scored 14 and 11 points in the example.

Team_Results stores results from events that more than one student took part in. It just stores the year group and points.

**The Aim**

I want to be able to produce a sum of points for each year - combined from both athletics_results and team_results. EG:

```
year   points
7      14     <-- No results in a_r, just 14 points in t_r
8      15     <-- 7 points in a_r (idResult 4) and 8 in t_r
11     43     <-- 14, 11, 9 points in a_r and 9 in t_r
```

**What I've tried**
For testing purposes, I've not tried combining the a_r scores and t_r scores yet but left them as two columns so I can see what's going on.

The first query I tried:

```
SELECT students.studentyear as syear, SUM(athletics_results.points) as score, SUM(team_results.points) as team_score
FROM students
JOIN team_results ON students.studentyear = team_results.year
JOIN athletics_results ON students.idStudent = athletics_results.idStudent
GROUP BY syear;
```

This gave different rows for each year (as desired) but had incorrect SUMS. I learnt this was due to not grouping the joins.

I then created this code:

```
SELECT studentyear as sYear, teamPoints, AthleticsPoints
FROM students st

JOIN    (SELECT year, SUM(tm.points) as teamPoints
        FROM team_results tm
        GROUP BY year) tr ON st.studentyear = tr.year 

JOIN    (SELECT idStudent, SUM(atr.points) as AthleticsPoints
        FROM athletics_results atr
        ) ar ON st.idStudent = ar.idStudent
```

Which gave correct SUMS but only returned one year group row (e.g the scores for Year 11).

EDIT - SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbc16/. This is with my actual test data which is a bigger sample than the data I posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad111/7

```
SELECT tr.`year`,  COALESCE(tr.points,0)+COALESCE(SUM(ar.points),0)
FROM Team_Results tr
LEFT JOIN Students s
ON tr.`year`=s.studentyear
LEFT JOIN Athletics_Results ar
ON s.idStudent = ar.idStudent
GROUP BY tr.year
```

According to your comment and fiddle provided
check  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbc16/3

```
SELECT tr.`year`,  COALESCE(tr.points,0)+COALESCE(SUM(ar.points),0)
FROM (
  SELECT `year`, SUM(points) as points
  FROM Team_Results
  GROUP BY `year`) tr
LEFT JOIN Students s
ON tr.`year`=s.studentyear
LEFT JOIN Athletics_Results ar
ON s.idStudent = ar.idStudent
GROUP BY tr.year
```

Comment: Tried it on my actual data and it didn't give the correct points. I've put my test DB on SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbc16/1/0. Your query gives a result of 21 and 582. There are only 333 points in the test DB in total so something is wrong.

Comment: so could you explain what your column `team_results.idEvents` stands for? should it be 2 records with year=11 or should it be agregated one record in result you expect?

Comment: Of course. idEvents links to a different table entirely (events) and is used to identify which event the points are related to. It shouldn't be relevant in this scenario. I'm expecting the output to have one row per year. The format of your output was correct but the sums were wrong.

Comment: Seems to be working now! I will do some further testing tomorrow but it looks like it works fine. Would you mind explaining the SQL code briefly?

Comment: I don't know what to explain... in subquery I prepare table `team_query` to by grouped and `SUM`ed by `year`

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in multiple ways. My first thought is:

```
SELECT idStudent, year, SUM(points) AS totalPoints FROM (
SELECT a.idStudent, c.year, a.points+b.points AS points
FROM students a
INNER JOIN Athletics_Results b ON a.idStudent=b.idStudent
INNER JOIN Team_Results c ON a.studentyear=c.year) d
GROUP BY idStudent,year
```

Comment: There's a syntax error - unexpected '(' after totalPoints. Adding a FROM before solves that but it still doesn't run. "Unknown column a.points". Changing a.points to c.points (there's no points column in the student table) resolves those errors, but the returned points aren't correct.

Comment: TYPO: Forgot the FROM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bfb1/1/0

```
SELECT 
    year, SUM(points)
FROM
    ((SELECT 
        a.year, SUM(b.points) AS points
    FROM
        student a
    JOIN at_result b ON b.student_id = a.id
    GROUP BY a.year) UNION (SELECT 
        a.year, SUM(a.points) AS points
    FROM
        t_result a
    GROUP BY a.year)) c
GROUP BY year;
```

On your data I get:

```
   year      points 
    7          14
    8          15
    11         43
```